# Error : dbeaver utility 'mysql.exe' not found in client home 'mysql binaries'

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

When I try to import an SQL file and execute it using [dbeaver software](https://dbeaver.io/), it prompts the following error:
[image]
I have already installed XAMPP on PC.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have here two possibilities.

First copy mysql.exe and mysqldump.exe into the dbeaver folder

or you change the `Local Client` the location in the c0onnection wizard

[image]

Comment: to open this connection settings:   right click on the connection and select edit connection

Answer (score 2):

I changed Local Client to 5.27 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this one and what worked for me is that I installed/reinstalled mysql client via

```
brew install mysql-client
```

After that, find the mysqldump exe in my local machine using this code

```
find / -name "mysqldump" 2>/dev/null
```

And then a list of paths will be displayed,just like this

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqldump
/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/bin/mysqldump
/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql-client/8.2.0/bin/mysqldump
/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.2.0_1/bin/mysqldump
```

Copy the path of mysqldump, in my case I copied

```
/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql-client/8.2.0/bin/mysqldump
```

And remove the 'bin/mysqldump' from the end

```
/System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql-client/8.2.0/
```

And paste it to the dbeaver local path.

PS. This is for MacOS.